# Separate business logic from controller in Play 2

Tags: java, playframework

I'm currently working on a minimal first time project with Play 2.2 framework (Java).
It's a very simple guess the number game.

It works, but I want to make it more pretty.

I tried to separate business logic from the controller to another class, so the controller class has only `static Result xyz()` methods, but it still has a static member of my business class and the appropriate action methods use it.

Is there a better way to make `Play` dynamically assign values and call methods on the business class instead of calling it from the controller class?

Comment: The idea behind play is to put all the business logic into the controller. The functions inside the controller on the other hand are not meant to return static results/html/strings/... but invoke a template. You can pass objects/variables to those templates, and use a (simple) template language to build your UI. Stuff you'll often do is looping through an array to create a html table, etc. Have a look at the corresponding documentation pages: http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.1/JavaTemplates

Comment: @Peanut Thanks I'll read the docs

Comment: @Peanut, the idea behind Play is exactly to NOT put business logic in the controllers. Put it in the model classes. Controllers serve as glue between HTTP and the business domain, doing stuff like form parsing and template rendering.

Comment: You can put in controller and turn it into transaction script pattern or you can put into model and have domain model instead. Ive also seen usage of Command and service layer. The description of patterns can be found in EAP ang GOF books. I am working with play for two weeks only right now, but I dont't see it is limiting developer to single approach.

Answer (score 0):

Play now makes it possible to use Spring Beans for both controllers and services. James Ward has created a sample application, available on github: https://github.com/jamesward/play-java-spring.

Answer (score 0):

I am working a framework that does just this.  It's available at https://github.com/ianrae/mettle-framework  but is totally experimental at the moment.

The idea is that your controller calls a presenter object that contains all the business logic.  Presenters can be unit tested with a very fast mock-db that doesn't require Play's FakeApplication.

Answer (score -1):

If I've understood you correctly the answer is you should use MVC or Model view control . It keeps the logic separted from UI

Comment: Thanks but you did not get my question. I'm already using MVC. I have my controller, model and view seperated already, but not as much as I seen in other frameworks, specifically, my controller class has a member of the model class. The question is, how to remove it and let Play instantiate etc.